# Viewpager returning null in fragment

Tags: android, xamarin.android

I have a fragment that holds a viewpager and tablayout. I can access the tablayout from the fragment but when I try to do the same for the view pager it always returns null

//this is a method on the pagefragment

```
public override void OnActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
  tabs = this.View.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.mytab);
   vp = (ViewPager) Activity.FindViewById(Resource.Id.myviewpage);

    SetUpViewPager(vp);
   tabs.SetupWithViewPager(vp);
}
```

vp alway returns null so the app crashes when it get to SetUpViewPager(vp) but the the tabs is accessible

Answer (score 0):

> I have a fragment that holds a viewpager and tablayout.

Problem is that you are hosting your `ViewPager` in a fragment, but you're trying to find it in the `Activity`. In the `Fragment`, you can code like this:

```
public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    var view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.fragment1, container, false);

    var tabs = view.FindViewById<TableLayout>(Resource.Id.mytab);
    var vp1 = (ViewPager)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.myviewpage);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: I have the same problem and your code does not work. Can you help me ?

Comment: Please see this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49177326/switch-to-tab-2-after-selecting-listview-from-tab-1