# Switch to tab 2 after selecting ListView from tab 1

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Here is a complete project: [Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1CbzT8rlxmnzxf64czEaflEl1MXdeuUd-).

Follow code:

**Frag_Home_1_Tab.cs:**

```
public class Frag_Home_1_Tab : Fragment
    {
        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        public static Frag_Home_1_Tab NewInstance()
        {
            return new Frag_Home_1_Tab { Arguments = new Bundle() };
        }


        public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            View inflate = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.frag_tab1, container, false);

            ListView mListView = inflate.FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.listView);

            ViewPager viewPager = inflate.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);

            mListView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
            {
                mListView.SetItemChecked(e.Position, true);

                // ** Here, how to navigate to tab 2 and refresh gridview **
            };

            ArrayAdapter<string> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemActivated1, List());

            mListView.Adapter = adapter;

            // Set the ChoiceMode
            mListView.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;

            // Select default
            mListView.SetItemChecked(0, true);

            return inflate;
        }

        private List<string> List()
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>
            {
                "List 1",
                "List 2",
                "List 3",
                "List 4",
                "List 5",
                "List 6",
                "List 7",
                "List 8",
                "List 9"
            };

            return list;
        }
    }
```

**frag_tab1:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <ListView
        android:minWidth="25px"
        android:minHeight="25px"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If you select from the "List5" list in tab 1, load 5 rows in the gridview of tab 2 and navigate to tab 2.

If you select from the "List9" list in tab 1, load 9 rows in the gridview of tab 2 and navigate to tab 2.

If you select from the "List2" list in tab 1, load 2 rows in the gridview of tab 2 and navigate to tab 2.

And so it goes ...

What I'm trying to say is: navigate to tab 2 when you click on tab button 1. Simple like that.

Any solution ?

Comment: Hi, in your post codes, by `var mTabHost = view.FindViewById<TabHost>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);` ,  `sliding_tabs` is `TabLayout`, not `TabHost`, so  your code confused me. I have post an answer, if it does works, please leave me a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Frag_Home_1`:

```
public class Frag_Home_1 : Fragment
{
    TabLayout tabLayout;
    private static class SingletonHolder
    {
        public static Frag_Home_1 INSTANCE = new Frag_Home_1();
    }
    public static Frag_Home_1 getInstance()
    {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }


    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View inflate = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.frag_home_1, container, false);

        ViewPager viewPager = inflate.FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.viewPager);
        MyFragmentPagerAdapter adapter = new MyFragmentPagerAdapter(ChildFragmentManager);
        viewPager.Adapter = adapter;

        //TabLayout 
        tabLayout = inflate.FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.sliding_tabs);
        tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        return inflate;
    }

    public void toTab2()
    {
        TabLayout.Tab tab = tabLayout.GetTabAt(1);
        tab.Select();
    }

    public class MyFragmentPagerAdapter : FragmentPagerAdapter
    {
        public string[] titles = new string[] { "Tab1", "Tab2" };
        List<Fragment> fgls = new List<Fragment>();
        public MyFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) : base(fm)
        {
            fgls.Add(Frag_Home_1_Tab.NewInstance());
            fgls.Add(Frag_Home_2_Tab.getInstance());
        }

        public override Fragment GetItem(int position)
        {
            return fgls[position];
        }

        public override ICharSequence GetPageTitleFormatted(int position)
        {

            return new String(titles[position]);
        }

        public override int Count
        {
            get { return titles.Length; }
        }
    }

}
```

`Frag_Home_1_Tab`'s `OnCreateView` method:

```
mListView.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
{
    mListView.SetItemChecked(e.Position, true);
    Frag_Home_1.getInstance().toTab2();
    Frag_Home_2_Tab.getInstance().updateGrid(e.Position);
    // ** Here, how to navigate to tab 2 and refresh gridview **
};
```

`Frag_Home_2_Tab`:

```
public class Frag_Home_2_Tab : Fragment,adapterUpdate
{
    ArrayAdapter<string> adapter;
    List<string> numbers = new List<string>();
    GridView grid;
    public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
    private static class SingletonHolder
    {
        public static Frag_Home_2_Tab INSTANCE = new Frag_Home_2_Tab();
    }
    public static Frag_Home_2_Tab getInstance()
    {
        return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        initData(9);
        View view = inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.frag_tab2, container, false);
        grid = (GridView)view.FindViewById(Resource.Id.gridview);

        grid.ChoiceMode = ChoiceMode.Single;

        grid.ItemClick += (sender, e) =>
        {
            grid.SetItemChecked(e.Position, true);
        };

        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.item_tab_2, numbers);

        grid.Adapter = adapter;

        return view;
    }

    private void initData(int count)
    {
        numbers.Clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            numbers.Add((i + 1).ToString());
        }
    }

    public void updateGrid(int count)
    {
        initData(count+1);
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<string>(Activity, Resource.Layout.item_tab_2, numbers);
        grid.Adapter = adapter;
    }
}

public interface adapterUpdate
{
    void updateGrid(int count);
}
```

In `Frag_Home_1` and `Frag_Home_2_Tab`, I use single instance to avoid `NullPointException`.

Comment: I can't find `ListView` in your axml. Or would you like to update your OneDrive?

Comment: How can I add tag?

Comment: I tried this way: `var Frag_Home_2_Tab = (Frag_Home_2_Tab) FragmentManager.FindFragmentByTag ("Frag_Home_2_Tab");` and returns as null.

Comment: Hi,@MatheusMiranda, Can you show the codes? You can use `if-else` to handle the null. If it is null, you need `SetTargetFragment` and then `Add`, else, you can use the object directly.